# Including/Getting razor file content in other razor file

Tags: c#, blazor, components

Good morning !

After a day searching via google without any kind of result (maybe don't use the good keywords ?)

Would like to know if there is a way to achieve this, or what is the best option to do this.

Here a simplified version of what I have:

- ItemCollection.razor

  - ItemCollection.razor.cs
- Element.razor

  - Element.razor.cs
- Element

  - Item.razor

    - Item.razor.cs

**Element.razor**

```
@namespace myns
@inherit ComponentBase

<style>
.element {
    height: @this.Height;
    width: @this.Width;

}
</style>
```

**Element.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class Element : ComponentBase
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

**Item.razor**

```
@namespace myns
@inherit Element

<style>
.item {
    background-color: aqua;
}
</style>
```

**Item.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class Item : Element
{
    public virtual string Class => return "item";
}
```

**DerivedItem1.razor**

```
@namespace myns
@inherit Item

<style>
.item {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
<div id="@base.ID" class="element @this.Class" onclick="(e) => this.OnClick(this, e)"></div>
```

**DerivedItem1.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class DerivedItem1 : Item
{
    public override string Class => base.Class + " derived1";
}
```

**DerivedItem2.razor**

```
@namespace myns
@inherit Item

<style>
.item {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<div id="@base.ID" class="element @this.Class" onclick="(e) => this.OnClick(this, e)"></div>
```

**DerivedItem2.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class DerivedItem2 : Item
{
    public override string Class => base.Class + " derived2"; 
}
```

**Collection.razor**

```
namespace myns;
@inherit ComponentBase

@foreach (var item in this.Items)
{
    @item ? here I would like to include/get the coresponding 
    Item.razor content according to the current item 
    and his derived class
}
```

**Collection.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class Collection<T> : ComponentBase
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Root.razor**

```
namespace myns;
@inherit ComponentBase

@Items => include Collection.razer content
```

**Root.razor.cs**

```
namespace myns;

public partial class Root : ComponentBase
{
    public Collection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it's clearly enough and thanks for the time !

So would like to know how to include/getting in a component .razor file the content of other .razor file. Like getting content of item while itering the list.

Comment: You don't create components or manage components: the render does.  So you can't do as you propose.  You define the data and then use components to display it.  You need to provide more context to suggest an alternative approach to your problem.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis for the context I would just like to create "templated collection iteration" avoiding iteration in collection.razor and load the content of item.razor whatever the type of item. Will modify a bit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ususally you can do this by using the razor component itself and passing the data to it as a parameter.

For example:

```cs
public class ItemData : Element 
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

Item.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class Item 
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public ItemData? Data { get;set; }
}
```

Item.razor

```
@if(Data is not null)
{
    <div id="@Data.ID" class="element @Data.Class" onclick="(e) => OnClick(this, e)"></div>
}
```

ItemCollection.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class ItemCollection : ComponentBase
{
    public List<DataItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

ItemCollection.razor

```
@foreach (var item in this.Items)
{
   <Item Data="item" />
}
```

Comment: I had thought of this solution, not exactly what I am looking for because I need to split into "data/wrapper". Just would like to know if it's possible to include/get/call something to say to generator, here include Item.razor for this "item".

Comment: You could try <Item @ref="item" />

Comment: I will get information about @ref still learning blazor, had to going to this for maui blazor, getting issue with maui alone, for example maui swipeview which doesn't work well on windows yet.